# What’s my voice type

Tags: voice

I know that classifying a voice type isn’t something I should focus on but I’m just curious about what I would be labeled as.
My speaking range is from G2/Ab2-D3/E3 (this is just when I speak, I tend to reach G2 when I’m tired or sick)
I am untrained and have never taken a singing class, but the highest my chest voice can push if I try is D4 and maybe F4. I don’t try and use head or falsetto since I don’t want to damage my chords since I’m not a trained singer but I feel in mixed and in head voice I could reach higher notes. Again, I know voice classification shouldn’t matter and that everyone has their own unique voice but I am curious what I would be labeled.

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably would be a tenor voice at the moment.
In 4 part voices, here is a possible voice range

Soprano - C4 to A5

Alto - F3 to C5

Tenor - A2 to F4

Bass - F2 to C4